# Is there a "LENIF" equivalent?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column populated with either "Very Small", "Small", or "Large". However, sometimes the system that creates this file adds extra characters in surprising locations. I'm wondering if there is a way to enter MAX and LEN with a conditional statement as an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (CSE)) so that it will  give me the maximum character count only for cells beginning with "Very", for instance.

As an example, for a column in which I can expect a consistent LEN, I can enter

`{=MAX(LEN(A1:A1000))}`

using CSE to know if there are any outliers greater than that given LEN that I need to address. The question is whether or not there's a way to do this, but conditionally based on the cell contents within that range.

I'm using Excel on Office365.

Comment: "However, sometimes the system that creates this file adds extra characters in surprising locations". This sounds a little bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), do you know *why* the system is adding extra characters?

Comment: I don't. And I don't have access to that system to make or suggest changes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
=MAX(LEN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Very",A1:A1000)),A1:A1000," ")))
```

As an array formula confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter

Now if you have the new Dynamic Array formula:

```
=MAX(LEN(FILTER(A1:A1000,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Very",A1:A1000))))
```

But if you simply want to "Clean" your data in a new column use:

```
=TRIM(CLEAN(A1))
```

And copy down.

Again with the new Dynamic Array formula one simple puts:

```
=TRIM(CLEAN(A1:A1000))
```

in the first cell of a new column and Excel will fill down.

Comment: You just sent me on a rabbit hole to learn more about the dynamic array formulas. Looking forward to when I have access to it! Your first formula has that extra step I was missing. Works great. I have a VBA sub to trim and clean, but on these amounts of data it can take a little bit, so I was looking for a way to test whether I needed to or not. This answer does it. Thanks!